# Obtaining instantaneous logic level of a PWM signal on STM32

Tags: stm32, pwm

I'm trying to figure out which of two PWM signals that are switching simultaneously is "1" at a given moment. Is there any way to obtain this information?

Comment: Do you mean in hardware or software? There's dozens of different STM32 MCU series available, is your question about some specific model?

Comment: Read the timer count register and see if it is in the window for PWM true output

Comment: @DeanFranks You can just read the GPIO state, no need to read timer count register for that.

Comment: They will switch simultaneously within the resolution of the program counter and set to the same PWM for dead-time insertion read RM0399 or watch https://youtu.be/uv4VXhzi7Ys

Comment: _"I'm trying to figure out which of two PWM signals that are switching **simultaneously** is "1" at a given moment."- That's easy. Since they are _simultaneous_, both will be either 1 or 0. Or did you mean something else? Why do you need this information?